# Ошибка "Unrecognized name" в запросе BigQuery

Tags: bigquery

Необходимо подсчитать количество сессий за весь диапазон дат выгруженной статистики. В качестве примера есть вот эта статья https://www.ga4bigquery.com/sessions-dimensions-metrics-ga4/. Основной запрос брала отсюда. Согласно комментариям, сменила count, однако система начала ругаться (Unrecognized name: event_name at [10:30]). Может, кто-то сталкивался? Как можно решить проблему? Спасибо

[image: скрин с ошибкой]

Полный запрос выглядит так:

```
-- subquery to define static and/or dynamic start and end date for the whole query
with date_range as (
select
    '20220601' as start_date,
    format_date('%Y%m%d',date_sub(current_date(), interval 1 day)) as end_date),

-- subquery to prepare and calculate engagement data
engagement as (
select
    count(distinct case when event_name = 'session_start' then concat(user_pseudo_id, cast(event_timestamp as string)) end) as sessions,
    sum(engagement_time_msec)/1000 as engagement_time_seconds,
    count(distinct case when session_engaged = '0' then concat(user_pseudo_id,session_id) end) as bounces
from (
    select
        user_pseudo_id,
        (select value.int_value from unnest(event_params) where key = 'ga_session_id') as session_id,
        max((select value.string_value from unnest(event_params) where key = 'session_engaged')) as session_engaged,
        max((select value.int_value from unnest(event_params) where key = 'engagement_time_msec')) as engagement_time_msec
    from
        -- change this to your google analytics 4 export location in bigquery
        `celtic-current-353007.analytics_309529570.events_*`,
        date_range
    where
      _table_suffix between date_range.start_date and date_range.end_date
    group by
        user_pseudo_id,
        session_id))

-- main query
select
    -- sessions (metric | the total number of sessions)
    count(distinct case when event_name = 'session_start' then concat(user_pseudo_id, cast(event_timestamp as string)) end) as sessions,
    -- engaged sessions (metric | the number of sessions that lasted longer than 10 seconds, or had a conversion event, or had 2 or more screen or page views)
    max(engaged_sessions) as engaged_sessions,
    -- engagement rate (metric | the percentage of engaged sessions compared to all sessions)
    safe_divide(max(engaged_sessions),count(distinct case when event_name = 'session_start' then concat(user_pseudo_id, cast(event_timestamp as string)) end)) as engagement_rate,
    -- engagement time (metric | the average length of time in seconds that the app was in the foreground, or the web site had focus in the browser)
    safe_divide(max(engagement_time_seconds),max(engaged_sessions)) as engagement_time,
    -- bounces (metric | the total number of non-engaged sessions)
    max(bounces) as bounces,
    -- bounce rate (metric | bounces divided by total sessions)
    safe_divide(max(bounces),count(distinct case when event_name = 'session_start' then concat(user_pseudo_id, cast(event_timestamp as string)) end)) as bounce_rate,
    -- event count per session (metric | number of times an individual event (i.e. 'page_view') was triggered divided by all sessions)
    safe_divide(count(distinct case when event_name = 'page_view' then concat(user_pseudo_id, cast(event_timestamp as string)) end),count(distinct case when event_name = 'session_start' then concat(user_pseudo_id, cast(event_timestamp as string)) end)) as event_count_per_session
from
    -- change this to your google analytics 4 export location in bigquery
    `celtic-current-353007.analytics_309529570.events_*`,
    date_range,
    engagement
where
    _table_suffix between date_range.start_date and date_range.end_date
```

Comment: **Кристина**, пожалуйста, приведите ваш код полностью, или дайте на него ссылку с помощью сайта `gist.github.com`

Comment: @alex, отредактировала свой вопрос, прописала код полностью

Comment: **Кристина**, спасибо, я вам за это выдал немного репутации :). Я совсем не разбираюсь в теме вашего вопроса, но может быть проблема в том, что окружение и вот этот ваш язык, на котором вы пишите - они не знают значение переменной `event_name`. Т.е. даже не значение, а система не может понять, что это такое `event_name`. Я, как человек, понимаю, что это `имя_события`, но ваше окружение этого не понимает :). Вообщем, не слушайте меня, тут может подтянутся спецы

Comment: @alex, спасибо вам за ответ)
В том-то и дело, что он понимает, что такое event_name, в таблице, из которой ее нужно вытянуть, она есть и значение, которое нужно вытянуть, тоже есть, но он почему-то выпендривается и не хочет мой запрос обрабатывать(

Comment: **Кристина**, попробуйте составить минимальный запрос. Т.е. попробуйте удалить всё что есть и написать минимум, например, `select * from имя_таблицы`. Затем постепенно добавлять `where` и таким образом выйти на ошибку ( это всё мои фантазии )

Comment: ещё раз я посмотрел на статью, ссылку на которую вы давали, так вот в этой статье `from` т.е. `из` написано ( в самой верхней картинке ) - из трёх таблиц, а в вашем примере - в вашем коде, только из двух таблиц

Comment: @alex, добрый день. Верхняя картинка просто не вся влезла для скрина)
Там снизу идут комментарии, которые не включились в скрин)

Answer (score 0):

у вас CTE `engagement` использует `event_name`, в выражении

```
count(distinct case when event_name = 'session_start' ...
```

пытаясь извлечь его из под-запроса где среди выбираемых колонок такого поля нет:

```
select
        user_pseudo_id, ...
```

вот и ошибка.

В статье в похожем месте используется не `event_name`, а агрегация `session_engaged` вычисленная в под-запросе.

Как решить - понять что вы хотите вычислить в под-запросе, возможно использовать `event_name` надо там, но это уже ваша логика.